# Getting the post ID in parse_query

Tags: hooks

I am creating a multilingual site, and trying to hook on to parse_query to throw a 404 if a specific translation doesn't exist (I have my own function to do the actual checking).

I can successfully throw a 404 if the language query var is not valid, but post_id's cannot be found (I have tried global $post, get_the_ID(), get_queried_object_id() etc).

$wp_query->get ('page_id) returns the ID of a page only, so not useful when on posts and custom post types.

Below is my current code:

```
function wf_lang_parse_query( $wp_query ) {
    
    if ( !is_admin() && ( $wp_query->get( 'lang' ) && !in_array( $wp_query->get( 'lang' ), wf_valid_lang() ) ) ):

        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );

    elseif ( !is_admin() &&  !wf_check_if_has_translations(THE ID GOES HERE, $wp_query->get( 'lang' )) ):

        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );

    endif;
    
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wf_lang_parse_query' );
```

Is it because that I am hooking on too early before post_id is available? Is there a hook that is available a bit later where I can get the Post ID and throw a 404 without causing issues?

Comment: This related question might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191877/using-wp-query-in-parse-query-or-pre-get-post-in-posts2posts

Comment: Also, have you tried the `pre_get_posts` hook? That might have more query details available.

Comment: `global $post, get_the_ID(), get_queried_object_id() ` etc won't be available until _after_ the query has ran, `parse_query` is too early and WP has only just figured out what the query vars should be, it hasn't fetched any posts or gone to the database yet. The same will be true of `pre_get_posts`. Likewise you need to check if the query is singular or not, you don't want to do this on a post archive/RSS feed/search/REST API listing/etc, and you need to check if it's the main query or not, otherwise your 404 will give warnings halfway down the page for widgets etc

Comment: also in some situations it won't know if there's a post that has been found yet, because maybe the query variable is `name=foo` and it won't know until it's gone to the database yet. Perhaps a later hook that's not related to query parsing would be more appropriate for this specific check. You should keep your check on the `lang` values validity here though, maybe even earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. After a bit of testing, I hooked onto WP (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) which occurs near the end of the WordPress loading sequence, and it is now working:

```
function wf_lang_query_check() {
    
    global $wp_query, $post;
    
    $lang =  wf_get_lang();
        
    if ( ( !is_admin() && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) && ( $lang && ( !in_array(  $lang, wf_valid_lang() ) || !wf_check_if_has_translations($post->ID,  $lang ) ) ) ):
    
       $wp_query->set_404();
       status_header( 404 );
        
    endif;
    
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wf_lang_query_check' );
```